# No puedo generar la BD a travez de EntityFramework Code First

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework, code-first

Estoy queriendo crear el modelado de datos a traves de EntityFramework con VisualStudio en el formato Code First , ya cree las clases y el contexto. Pero con la siguiente cadena de conexcion:

```
 <connectionStrings>

<add name ="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDBFileName=|DataDirectory|\CajaDB.mdf;Initial Catalog=CajaDB; Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Me arroja el siguiente error:

> A file activation error occurred. The physical file name '\CajaDB.mdf' may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation.
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

Me ayudarian a ver cual es el problema, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes el servicio local en la pc podrias hacer que esta se cree directamente en  `sql server`sin indicar un `AttachDBFileName`

```
Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=CajaDB; Integrated Security=True
```

Tambien revisaria el parametro de `User Instance=true`

[Bad habits : Using AttachDBFileName](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/)

Tambien probaria cambiando `Data Source=.\MSSQLLocalDB;`

Verifica que el nombre de la instancia `MSSQLLocalDB` es correcto conectandote desde el `Management Studio`

Comment: Realiazando las modificaciones que me sugeriste dejo de arrojarme el error. Pero por lo que veo no me esta creando la BD. Entro al LocalDB de SQL a través del Managment Studio y no me aparece. Sabras a que se debe?

Comment: A su vez, se supone que en el explorador de servidores de visual studio me debería figurar la base de datos que me genero. Pero directamente no me figura ninguna conexión por defecto.

Comment: pero el localdb tiene una instancia? o es solo localdb. Si defines una db indicando la ruta no vas a visualizarla dentro del servicio porque es un attach dinamico, por eso comente que quites el `AttachDBFileName`. Valida que te conectas usando seguridad integrada, o sea cuando usas el `Management Studio` no ingreses usuario y password

Comment: Si quite el AttachDBFileName, Y valide el servidor de localdb con el Managment Studio.
La cadena de conexion me quedo asi:
`<add name="entityFramework" connectionString="Data Source=.\Servidor; Initial Catalog=CajaDB; Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: la instancia se llama `Servidor` ? o sea cuando instalaste sql server indicaste ese nombre para la instancia de la db?

Comment: Si si le puse ese nombre, por nada en especifico.

Comment: Que pasa si creas la db usando el `Management Studio` y ejecutas la aplicacion? te crea la estructura de tablas?